# Unconventional spells in magicka

Tags: magicka

What are some spells you use other than Double-Super-Soaker-Lightening-Beam (and shield)?

I've discovered that healing rocks (life + earth) self cast is better than just life self cast, and heals your party around you, and is very strong when fighting undead. What are some other useful combinations?

Comment: I'm worried this might be too open-ended.  It sounds like "Build a list of what you like", which is not a good type of question for this site.

Comment: I thought there was a "community wiki" button that would appear when I posted; there wasn't. I guess that's a StackOverflow thing.

Comment: Please review the section titled "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" in the [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq). This question is both open-ended and is attempting to build a list. Both of these types of questions fall into the category of "I want to have a discussion about this topic" and not "I want a definitive answer to a question on this topic". Such questions are better asked in our community chat. :)

Comment: Community Wiki implies the question need collaboration.  In this case there is no need to collaborate on your question.  Currently Community Wiki is disabled on questions as the need for a collaborative question is very rare.  However, anyone writing an answer may feel the need to collaborate, and thus any answer can be marked as CW.  I hope this helps you understand how Community Wiki works.

Comment: SEDFQS then shift right-click: it spawns a large shield of rocks around you infused with other elements. They explode for lots of damage if you drop a SEF shift right-click ring of bombs after.